# Attrs behaves weird for each version of odoo

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-domain

I have seen weird behaviour of **attrs** in odoo for all versions (v8, v9,v10).

I want to know the reason why odoo frameworks behaves like that.

[image]

I have listed domains for m2m fields / o2m fields which I have tested for all versions, why it's version specific ?

I have written **Yes** if the domain is working for that version otherwise written **No**.